# Read and Update config.php in PHP

Tags: php

So, I wonder if someone can help me and give me an example of what I need to do, I am creating a website for myself and some friends and have a config file, called config.php in this format

```
<?php
$yourname = "";  // Set this to your name
$base = ""; //Set this to your url (without http://)


$user = ""; // Username for logging on
$pass = ""; // Password for logging on

$sabvisible = ""; // Set to turn on or off links (0 = Off 1 = On)
$sabport = "";  // Set the ports for your services
?>
```

This is just a small cut of the config, but that is the format/layout..

What I want to do is make a page that can read this file in, and allow people to set the options and save the variable back to the file, So I guess a page with a box called UserName and the username entered would update the variable in the config file when the page is posted? I'm just not too sure how to do it, if someone could give me an example for 1 of the fields, I will be able to work it for the rest of the config file.

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Karl

Comment: You need create a form that lets the user enter his details and submits it to your php file.

Comment: That's not exactly difficult. A regex appraoch can constrain already which syntactic parts to modify, and which to leave alone (comments). But would require more than just an example really. There's a few existing implementations for "non-destructive config.php editing" even.. Though they'll mostly use arrays rather than single globals / local vars.

Comment: Ok, is there a better/easier approach I can take? I don't mind changing the config file format (as long as I can get my php site to read the values in still) Or should I just give up with the idea?

Thanks for the responses people

Comment: You could use another format to store your data in, such as ini, json, yaml or anything like that.

Comment: Ok, so if I converted to ini, what would be the process or reading/writing the file, is there an example somewhere I can look at (hack to my working)?